# Factor out code from knockout event bindings in templates

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dozen of templates, each requires an event handling that looks like

```
event: { 
 vclick: function (data, event) { 
  $parents[1].cellClick($parents[1].rows()[$parentContext.$index()], data, event) 
    } 
}
```

How can I make this shorter and better to handle? I tried moving the event handler into the viewmodel, but I am having troubles passing around the binding context properties ($parents etc.)

Edit: there was a missing $ in $parentContext.$index() and this is the cellClick code, it really does nothing special:

```
self.cellClick = function (row, data, event)
{
    var rowData = self.getRowObject(row.Items());
    var cellData = rowData[data.Key()];
    self.rowClickHandler(cellData, rowData, event);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So `vclick` calls `cellClick`, which will then call `rowClickHandler`. What does `rowClickHandler` do? Instead of jumping through all the click handlers, it might be better to directly call the function you want to execute.

Comment: "rowClickHandler" is supposed to be set by the user, while "cellClick" is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move it to your viewmodel if you pass the parent and its index:

```
vclick: function(data, evt) { 
    $root.vclick(data, event, $parents[1], $parentCountext.index()); 
}
```

Then in your viewmodel it might look like this:

```
self.vclick = function(data, event, parent, rowIndex) {
    parent.cellClick(parent.rows()[rowIndex], data, event);
};
```

But this does not feel right. If you could share some more code (`cellClick`?), we can determine whether there's a better approach.

Comment: Thank you, I used this suggestion, the final expression is not that much shorted but definitely more readable:  ´event: { vclick: function (data, event) { $parents[1].cellClick(data, event, $parentContext.$index()); } }´

Answer (score 1):

You can try this binding:

```
event: { mouseover: $parents[1].myOver.bind($data, $parentContext, $parents[1]) }
```

With the function `myOver` in your item's grand-parent's model:

```
this.myOver = function (parentContext, parents1) { 
    alert("Data: " + JSON.stringify(parents1)); 
}
```

In which you will be able to access `$parentContext` with variable parentContext, `$parents[1]` with `parents1` and your item's binding (`$data`) with `this`.

See this example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/a233x/)**

Comment: This looks good, only he event is missing (and event.target is required later in the code). To get that, I have to wrap the expression into a function (event) statement again, right? It will then not be much shorter than the original expression. But at least the long expression is factored our.